# Why Respose.redirect changing the URL naming case

Tags: c#, asp.net

My problem as below:

I deployed my website in IIS7 with a name "WebTest". 
Now I am able to access the URL with different naming conventions like "webtest", "WEBTEST".

I do have code redirect in some places as below..`Response.Redirect("~/myasp.aspx")`

Whenever url redirect happen site url is automatically adjusted to "WebTest".

This issue is happening in Only Server only.

Can some please share your ideas me why it is happening

Thanks,
Pavan

Comment: that looks like normal IIS behavior.

Comment: @bansi .. I felt the same.. But I want to stop that behavior(ie., manipulating the URL name to default case)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`IIS` runs on `Windows`. `Windows'` file system is case insensitive. This means that to `IIS`, `http://webtest` and `http://WEBTEST` are the same thing.

If you would like case sensitive URLs, then you need to use a webserver running on a file system which is case sensitive, such as a flavor of `Linux` and `Apache`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply .. I would like to know why Response.Redirect("~/myasp.aspx") is manipulating the URL to default webdeployment name.

Comment: @PavanKumarkota Because you are using the `~` to direct to the base URL. IIS only has access to the default name, so it uses that to create the URL to redirect to.